# update field in a table with another field in same table and set the second field equal to 0 in as400

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, db2-400

Currently this is what I am trying:

```
UPDATE File1
 SET Field1 = 'A', Field2 = ' ', SH_QY = QTY_CAN, QTY_CAN = 0
 WHERE
     OD_NR IN
          (SELECT OD_NR FROM file2 WHERE DELVY_TYPE = 'ABCD')
 AND
      OD_NR IN
          (SELECT OD_NR FROM file3 WHERE ID_CD = 'XYZ')
 AND  Field2 = 'H'
```

This works when i run this interactively in SQL400, but when i run this in program it makes both SH_QY and QTY_CAN = 0

Please help.

Comment: What's the QTY_CAN value before the UPDATE?

Comment: When you run it in what program? Show the code that doesn't work. The comment from jarlh is also important especially because of commitment control.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can be guaranteed that the SET clause earlier in the line will be executed before the end of the line. The optimizer can do it in whichever order it wants to. As much as it's a pain, I would recommend doing that in two statements. That way, you're guaranteed that it'll do what you want.

HTH,
DaveSlash